# I added a new path to apple-app-site-association file but still doesn't work

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I added a new path `/pass/` to `www.viki.com/apple-app-site-association` file but still doesn't work. When I open `www.viki.com/pass`, it still opens Safari. The URL `www.viki.com/tv/1234` still works and opens the iOS app. What is the problem?

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "SNU9N24VYW.com.viki.viki-ios",
                "paths": [ "/tv/*", "/videos/*", "/pass/" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple things I did to fix this.

- Delete the app and reinstall to make it reload apple-app-site-association (AASA) file.
- While I see request to both

http://www.viki.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association and

http://www.viki.com/apple-app-site-association,

it actually uses the one at `/.well-known/`. So need to update that instead.

- for `paths` array, seems like
  `/pass` entry works with both `/pass` and `/pass/` urls, **BUT**
  `/pass/` only works with `/pass/` url. So I think it's better to use the one WITHOUT slash.

*Extra*: Another tip you can use to debug this is to use Charles Proxy to mock the `apple-app-site-association` response to something you want to test.

Comment: Is .well-known actually necessary? Would everything "just work" if you would not put AASA file there?

Comment: @OleksiyIvanov I guess the .well known is the first place it checks when you are using safari in ios 9+.
It'll work if you configure the domain as `https://www.somedomain.com/apple-app-site-association`

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked was deleting the app that was installed from Xcode, downloading it from the App Store, deleting it, and then installing from Xcode again.